# Running terminal commands with a double click file

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a program that I have to run by going into the terminal and typing "./filename". I want make an executable file that types this automatically for me.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. Does the application need to be run from its own directory and do you just need the command to be run, or you want or need it to be run from a terminal?   (What is the application?)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a `.desktop` file to start your `filename`. See [How to Create a .desktop](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/) and [The Gnome page](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

Also read `man desktop-file-validate;man desktop-file-install`.